# Некорректная работа программы при запуске jar файла через консоль Windows 10

Tags: java, изображения, javafx, jar

Разрабатывал программу на языке Java в среде разработки Eclipse. В программе предусмотрен графический интерфейс, написанный с помощью JavaFX.

Мне необходимо собрать jar файл, который будет корректно работать при запуске через терминал.
При использовании команды:

```
java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml -jar
```

Название файла.jar открывается нужное окно, но почему-то пропадают все картинки. Я обратил внимание, что если открыть jar файл, как архив, папки images (созданной мной) с изображениями там не будет. То же самое с аудиофайлами. Решил добавить их вручную, после этого файл перестал запускаться через консоль вообще.

Я не использую в своем проекте сборщики Maven или Gradle.
Что мне сделать с jar файлом, чтобы при запуске через консоль отображались картинки?
В программе пути к картинкам описаны в FXML файлах.
Пример из FXML файла:

```
 <ImageView fitHeight="650.0" fitWidth="1212.0" layoutX="-126.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../images/Settings/settingsFon.jpg" />
         </image>
 </ImageView>
```